# How can we use bold/italics inside MathJax tables?

Tags: support, formatting, mathjax

In [this Q&A](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6336/35259), it is shown that we can use MathJax to create tables (see [this answer](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6337/35259) in particular). However, as I attempt to use it, I find myself unable to add the text formatting I wish to use.

Here are my attempts:

> $$
> \begin{array}{c|l}
> \text{**I want this to be bold**}& \text{*I want this to be italics*} \\
> \hline
> \text{***I want this to be bold italics***} & \text{_I want this to be italics too_} \\
> \end{array}
> $$

As you can see, it doesn't quite obey the markdown formatting like I expect it to. MathJax must have it's own way of specifying it; either that, or it simply isn't possible.

Is it possible to have simple text formatting (i.e. **bold**, *italics*, etc) for the text (i.e. the "Some Text" within this `\text{Some Text}`)?

Comment: Semi-relevant MSE post: [Stack Exchange is rolling out native table support that isn't reliant on MathJax](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/356997/335251). It goes into testing today on MSE and on the DBA Meta, then rolls out to DBA.SE itself a week later, and will be available network-wide a week after that. It uses "GitHub-flavored Markdown" table syntax (since CommonMark doesn't include a specification for tables at the moment).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By looking at this [related meta](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/662809) from Math SE, I found these formatting options which I think may be what you want. You can use `\textit` and `\textbf` for italicised and bolded text. For mathematical symbols only, you can use `\mathbf` and `\mathit`.

```
$$
\begin{array}{c|l}
\textbf{I want this to be bold}& \textit{I want this to be italics} \\
\hline
\pmb{\textit{I want this to be bold italics}} & \textit{I want this to be italics too} \\
\end{array}
$$
```

This produces this result:

> $$
> \begin{array}{c|l}
> \textbf{I want this to be bold}& \textit{I want this to be italics} \\
> \hline
> \pmb{\textit{I want this to be bold italics}} & \textit{I want this to be italics too} \\
> \end{array}
> $$

Comment: Awesome, thanks for this. I have looked at some of the math.meta before, but there's so much there I found it difficult to find what I was looking for.

Comment: There are also the two commands `\textbf{}` and `\textit{}` for bold and italicised text in math mode respectively.

Comment: Readers please note that there are about fifty different ways to do *anything* in *TeX; if you're googling around you'll probably find a bunch of other ways to achieve the same effect(s).

Comment: Please don’t recommend math mode for text: use `\textbf`, `\textit`, or `\emph` for text formatting. `\emph` should be used when text is italicized for emphasis, and can be nested (`\emph` inside an already-italic section will make the `\emph` text *not* italic). `\textit` is for book titles, D&D spells, and other things italicized as a matter of formatting and not emphasis. Bold-italic should just be `\textbf{\textit{whatever}}`. `\pmb`, or “poor man’s bold,” is just a bad idea all around, and will often not give desirable results.

Comment: @KRyan I've updated the post to mention those, but it looks like `\textbf{\textit{{whatever}}` doesn't nest — the inner textit gets interpreted as plaintext. I don't know what to put there instead so I've left `\pmb` in, as bad as it is.