# Why does inline math require \ before $?

Tags: support, markdown, mathjax

I just asked [this](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/169813/how-do-i-calculate-d20-success-probability-using-the-halfling-lucky-trait-with) question, but my inline math didn't work until I put a backslash before the dollar signs `\$like so\$`.

Why is the backslash required? That isn't the case on other sites.

> [image: ![Screenshot]

Comment: I came here to ask if it's just me, and found it was already asked. I confirm the issue, and added a screenshot to illustrate the issue.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Sometimes, when MathJax is added to a site when it's mature and has a lot of posts already, Stack Exchange staff chooses to use `\$` delimiters instead of `$`. This is to prevent things like

> There are a few decent options in the $10-$20 range.

being displayed as

> There are a few decent options in the \$10-\$20 range.

There are a handful of other sites in the network where this the case: for a complete list, see [Which Stack Exchange sites use MathJax?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/216607/295232).

Comment: That's cool. Thanks. Out of interest, how would one write $10-$20 in sites which do not use \$?

Comment: Surprise, surprise (I didn't know it either, I [just tried](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/31827/228959)): that's possible by using `\$`.

Comment: haha, nice, thankyou

Answer (score 9):

Because when we added MathJax to the site, [Stack Exchange staff decided](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6335/1204) to use `\$` as delimiters rather than `$` because many posts would be impacted otherwise. They cite [an analysis by one of our citizens](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5896/mathjax-latex-equations-for-rpg-se-and-statistics-posts#comment16641_5899):

> There are 349 posts that contain dollar signs, more than twice my estimate for posts that might benefit from MathJax (162). 137 of the 349 contain 2 dollar signs, if that matters.
>
> *— Miniman Nov 12 '15 at 0:37*

You can see the [original post requesting MJ on RPG here](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5896/23970), and [the post announcing its going live here](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6336/23970).

(I know this doesn't really add much to Glorfindel's answer—really I just wanted to link both of those posts into this conversation, and my conscience wouldn't let me leave them in comments that really do answer the question.)

Comment: Thanks for sharing that info! I think the answer does add something :)