# Should we turn on MathJax in comments?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, comments, mathjax

We have MathJax turned on for posts, but not comments. We do get some math-heavy posts from time to time, which is why we have MathJax in  posts, but we don't have it turned on for comments like they do over at Math.se.

It would be nice to be able to include MathJax in comments for those posts where clarification questions would include formulas.

Could it be abused? Technically, yes, [but similar abuse is possible in posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/135347/674198), and we don't see that happening.

Comment: Related meta about posts: [MathJax (LaTeX equations) for RPG.SE and Statistics Posts](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5896)

Comment: An additional aspect that any answer should integrate is the intended temporary nature of comments and whether we want to lend comments more weight in that way.

Comment: @Akixkisu What do you mean by "lend comments more weight in that way"?

Comment: Generally, we want to integrate comments into answers/questions where appropriate. Whenever we add tools to comments that remove the necessity to put them into answer/question form, we invite more comments that can stand independently. I believe that any answer should consider that aspect.

Comment: Is the question here if we *can* turn them on or if we *want* to? The former would be answered really only by mods and staff, the latter by anybody. Personally, I see no reason *not* to turn them on, but I don't know that others feel the same way, after all, they aren't on on all of Stack presumably for *some* reason

Comment: @Exempt-Medic Giving me flashbacks to kindergarten mate - Teacher: "I don't know, *can* you go to the bathroom?"

Comment: Um, wait, doesn't \$\LaTeX\$ work in comments already? You just need to use the same `\$` delimiters as in posts.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen \$What\$

Comment: @IlmariKaronen I swear I tested it before asking this question.

Comment: @ThomasMarkov Maybe you only tried the single dollar sign variant ($this$)? That's what works in comments on Math.SE but wouldn't work here.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

#### We already have this.

As pointed out by Ilmari Karonen, we already have this. I need to make sure none of my user scripts on my desktop interfere with it somehow, because I’m quite confident I tested it before asking this question, in order to avoid how silly I look right now.

Comment: No harm done. Sometimes the best way to discover a feature already exists is to ask for it!